# Join by nearest Error: Could not convert value "LSU" to target type

Tags: qgis, error, spatial-join, qgis-modeler, proximity

I am trying to join a point shapefile to nearby sampling locations in the Graphical Modeler, but the following red text appears in the model log:

[image: Snippet of Log.]

> Feature could not be written to
> Joined_layer_9727c384_2299_4a83_92de_32f907acb6f9: Could not store
> attribute "fish_elev1": Could not convert value "LSU" to target type

The following item is also written in black:

> Multiple matching features found at same distance from search feature,
> found 4 features instead of 3.

I looked at the output attribute table and it is blank. I am at a loss on how to solve this. I don't know why the fields and associated values are not able to be joined.

Comment: Can you please show us a snippet of your data before the join by nearest process? Can you perform the same procedure without a graphical model? Is your data valid/clean/topologically correct?

Comment: I can perform the operations outside the graphical model using the two files it outputs.  I have this problem with another task in the model as well.  What do you mean a snippet of my data.  I can give you the two shapefiles I would like to join by value for this operation.